# Using the If conditional with sessions in PostgreSQL+PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, if-statement

My doubt is quite simple probably, but as a first time for me, this things get confusing
My PHP code is basically a session based one where each person gets texts to display on their page once logged in, but each person gets different ones, and those are saved on a database with their names too
So I need to know how would I make the query on php to get the information belonging to my current user
Something like

```
if(user=="John"){
  display(documents of John);
}
```

Of course "documents of John" is a field instead
But, hopefully you can get the idea

Thanks

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = '".$user."'`. Assuming username is your column name in database.

Answer (score 0):

use the `user` and run a sql query to get `document`  from `documents` table where `username = user`. Retrieve the data. 
You got the document related to that unique user.

Comment: Users are on a table and they are related to the table Documents
So in the session i should check the kind of users, like Students or Professors(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: suppose your user's type is set to session variable user_Type. So add  " AND type = user_Type " in your WHERE clause.